# one contact id giving two similar numbers

Tags: android, android-contacts, telephonymanager

I am getting all the contact number from my contact list, I have applied log to check values and few contact ids giving numbers like

*id 22261 name ABC*

*id 22261 Number ‪+91 98765 43210‬*

*id 22261 Number +919876543210*

other contacts saved in similar manner giving proper response

I have tried few alteration, if I pass phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER, it solves the above problem but it returns few contact numbers as *null*

Here is my Code to read Contacts

```
Cursor cursor_number=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor_number!=null){

            if (cursor_number.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    contact_id=cursor_number.getString(cursor_number.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name=cursor_number.getString(cursor_number.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                    if(Integer.parseInt(cursor_number.getString(cursor_number.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))>0){
                        Cursor cursor_number1=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{contact_id},null);
                        while (cursor_number1.moveToNext())
                        {
                            String number = cursor_number1.getString(cursor_number1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
// To add number to an ArrayList
                            details.add(number);
                            }
                        cursor_number1.close();
                    }
                }
                while (cursor_number.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO CONTACTS TO DISPLAY",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        cursor_number.close();
}
```

is there any mistake in my code? guidance needed, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked on the contacts and found out few points.

Please read [this official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) too for more details.

1. Id is the unique identifier given to a group of contacts merged together. For example, your contact can be saved as Gaurav 9876543210, Gaurav 1234567890 or Gaur 9876543210 or Gaur gaurav@gmail.com, At the end all this data is merged into single contact Gaurav. So all the multiple contact details will be given a single and unique ID.
2. In short, IDs are unique for a unique contact group. It can have multiple data associated with it.

Comment: yeah but both contact numbers are same and I have saved them only once